# Run-time error '1004: Subtotal method of range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to run a subtotal on a specific sheet (List) using the following code;

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("List").Activate

Columns("A:G").Select

Selection.Subtotal GroupBy:=7, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(4, 5, 6)
```

However keep getting the following error (highlighting the final row of code);

Run-time error '1004:

Subtotal method of Range class failed

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Is there any data in the range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you're working on the worksheet that you think you are. 
To confirm this, replace

```
ActiveWorkbook.Activate
```

with

```
ActiveWorkbook.Select
```

They are not equivalent. In order to avoid this in the future, explicity work on your desired sheet like this:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("List")

ws.Columns("A:G").Subtotal GroupBy:=7, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(4, 5, 6)
```

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180008/excel-select-vs-activate) has some good answers indicating what I believe to be your issue. Particularly [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7188721/3198973).

Answer (score 0):

I have this error on Delphi, the decision has helped is setting of numerical values ​​for xlSum = -4157 and xlSummaryBelow = 1 (look here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-subtotal-method-excel)