# How can I traverse a column and copy its values to two more columns?

Tags: vba, excel

I have been trying to create a macro that will go through a spreadsheet and copy figures in Cells E,  then paste them into Cell K and L, then repeat as the macro transverse column E. i.e. E1 will be copied to K1 and L1, E2 will be copied to K2, L2 etc...

This is what i have done so far:

```
Sub uy()
'
' Macro1 Macro
' lo
'
   Range("E299").Select
      Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
         If ActiveCell.Value < 0 Then
            Selection.Copy
            Range("K299").Select
                Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
            Loop
            Range("L299").Select
                Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
            Loop
         Else
            Range("L299").Select
                Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
                    ActiveSheet.Paste
            Loop
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Loop
End Sub
```

When i run the macro it just highlights cell E229 with a broken line box and Cells K299, L299 are left blank. I feel `Range("K299").Select, Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell),                    ActiveSheet.Paste` part is selecting and copying a blank cell, so it will terminate itself as it meets the "Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)" criteria.

Is there a way for me to fix this?

Comment: I won't post as an answer because I'm not sure, but try changing `select` to `activate` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180008/excel-select-vs-activate

Comment: can't you do this with worksheet formulas in the target/destination cells? You could try `=IF(E299<0,E299,"")` then copy that down and in columns K and L

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this would work.

```
Sub Copy()

    Dim intRowCount as Long
    Dim intLastRow as Long

    intRowCount = 2
    intLastRow = Application.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("e:e"))

    For intRowCount = 2 To intLastRow
        Sheets(1).Range("K" & intRowCount ).Value = Sheets(1).Range("E" & intRowCount ).Value
        Sheets(1).Range("L" & intRowCount ).Value = Sheets(1).Range("E" & intRowCount ).Value
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Edited your answer and changed `Integer` to `Long`. It's better practice in this case. Also, changed `Set intRowCount = 2` to `intRowcount = 2`. `Set` is not needed there, it's not an object. Also, quality-wise, `Application.CountA(Sheets(1).Range("e:e"))` can pose some severe problems in getting the last row. What if there are blanks? They won't be counted using this, which might give you a lower number than expected. Lastly, try using `Union` for the equivalence part to bring it down to one line. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if i got you right.
but if you want to just copy one range to an other then
this would do it.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
      For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
            If Cells(i, 5) <> "" Then
                  Cells(i, 11).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value
                  Cells(i, 12).Value = Cells(i, 5).Value
            End If
      Next i
End Sub
```

This marco works as long as cell 'i' in column E isn't empty
and takes the value of cell 'i' in column E and puts it into column K and L

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use `Activate` or `Select`. They're 99% useless in most code. Next, don't use copy and paste. It's slow for this kind of approach.

The following code is much more streamlined and faster.

```
Sub EtoKL()

    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim LRow As Long, Iter As Long

    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change as necessary.
    With WS
        LRow = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Get last used row in Column E.
        For Iter = 1 To LRow 'Iterate from 1 to last used row.
            Union(.Range("K" & Iter), .Range("L" & Iter)).Value = .Range("E" & Iter).Value
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Let us know if this helps.