# Avoiding Activate by saving files when using many workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have a special cases, where I cannot find a way around `Activate` which is considered to be bad (slow) coding in VBA. In this case I am looping over sheets of an original workbook, copy contents from those sheets - under certain conditions - then paste these contents into a new workbook and finally try to save the result to csv-files. I am doing this by using the following save-routine:

```
Private Sub saveWorksheet(pathx, wbkn, sheetn)

path = pathx & ".csv"
Workbooks(wbkn).Sheets(sheetn).Activate

Workbooks(wbkn).SaveAs Filename:=path, _
FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True, CreateBackup:=False

End Sub
```

If I don't use `Activate` I get an error. Is there any way to avoid it when saving files?

edit: Some info on why `Activate` is considered bad:
[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)
[Excel Select vs Activate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180008/excel-select-vs-activate)

edit2: After some research and testing, I found out that the problem is not the save method itself, but rather the context of multiple workbooks being involved. I do not think you can prevent `Activate` when saving a file from *another* workbook or also when running a macro on *another* workbook, while doing also stuff on the 'original' base-workbook. You can only prevent its use when you are working on the same (ie 'original') workbook all the time.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: You are attempting to save as a CSV. This means that you can only save the single current worksheet in a multi-worksheet workbook.

Comment: @MatthewD I cannot check this right now, but I will add the information as soon as possible. Thanks for your interest.

Comment: @Jeeped I know that. But that means I have to activate it? Is not usually enough to just refer to the objects thoroughly, like up to the parent etc.?

Comment: I have done alot of Excel programming and i have never had anything slow even though i activate all the time to switch sheets.  If you are not having any performance issues , i wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: MatthewD alright that sounds very good, but I got kind of curious - why do we sometimes need to Activate and sometimes we don't, that is so confusing to me. In my code, I was able to avoid it 95% of times now just by referencing clearly, but I don't understand why it is not possible in the above case. Moreover, btw, it is also not possible to avoid when running a routine from another workbook, by using a macro in the currently opened workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you want to save a sheet as csv, why dont you use the worksheet in question directly. workbook save as csv requires to know the active sheet

```
Private Sub saveWorksheet(pathx, wbkn, sheetn)
    dim ws as worksheet
    path = pathx & ".csv"
    set ws = worksheets(sheetn)
    ws.SaveAs Filename:=path, FileFormat:=xlCSV, Local:=True, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Krishna thanks for your reponse. I am using an older vers of Excel and there was some bug by trying to save Worksheets directly before. I will check it again though